# Determine the number of reducible degree two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Would the strategy be to find all of the irreducible degree two polynomials and subtract that from the total amount? And is the total amount of polynomials of degree two $p^2$, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducible means they factor because of the low degree. So write out the polynomial

$$f(x) = a(x-b)(x-c)$$

How many choices are there for each value? There are $p-1$ non-zero multipliers, $a$, and $p(p+1)/2$ choices for $(b,c)$ where order doesn't matter.

Comment: So for degree three polynomials do we have $f(x) = a(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$?

Comment: @Jmars no, because reducible in degree $3$ can also be an irreducible linear factor times an irreducible quadratic factor.